# Using a local static image as ArrayBuffer in a React TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, file-upload, react-typescript

I'm working on a React TypeScript project and I have an issue when trying to use a local static image as an ArrayBuffer. I have a function called uploadImage that takes an imageFile, filePath, and fileName as parameters.

Here's the code for the function:

```
const imageFile = require('./uploads/image.png');

async function uploadImage(imageFile: string, filePath: string, fileName: string): Promise<string> {
  const response = await fetch(imageFile);
  const imgBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
  console.log('img ' + imgBuffer);
}
```

I would like to use a local static image in this function and convert it into an ArrayBuffer. However, when I use fetch to get the image file, it doesn't work as expected.

How can I properly use a local static image and convert it into an ArrayBuffer in my React TypeScript project? Any help would be appreciated.

I also just tried to display the picture but its not working so I guess its why the buffer is not good just doing a :

```
    <img src={imageFile} alt="My Image" />
```

display a broken picture